# Export vector tiles or save them locally using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, vector-tiles

I'm using QGIS 3.30 and have added a vector tile layer in the format [https://privateurl.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://privateurl.com/tiles/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf). I would like to be able to export this at zoom level 14 to local files so I can do additional analysis on the polygons. Does anyone know if this is possible?

The usual right-click->export>save as... is greyed out.

Comment: you can just request the tiles that you need directly in a web browser or with curl

Comment: Do you want to analyze the tiles in .pbf format or as converted into some GIS format?

Comment: I want to convert them into a GIS format. So they are still georeferenced. This is why just downloading the tiles using a browser doesn't work as they lose the location.

Comment: Vector tiles are not georeferenced. Or, they are georeferenced only indirectly by the tile number- if tile number is this and tiling schema is that then the software knows where to render the data of the tile. MVT layer is not a real vector layer for QGIS https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsVectorTileLayer.html and that's why export option in QGIS is greyed out.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to identify how QGIS generates the x and y values to pass? The layer CRS is ESPG 3857.